# Java adding two arrays of objects

Tags: java

Done quite a but of digging but cant seem to find an answer.

I have 2 object arrays. These objects are session counts, which contain data about our servers. Each `SessionCount` object has:

- Date
- Hour
- number of connections

So of the two `SessionCount` arrays, I need to match up the objects date and hour, then use that to add the number of connections for that time. Any ideas?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Basically you're searching for common elements between the arrays and *join* them. Use a `Map<SessionCount, SessionCount>` for this and make sure to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `SessionCount`.

Comment: This looks like a MapReduce use case.You emit a key (date,hour) in map phase and reduce would just printout out aggregated and summed output.You can use a 
private Map<String,SessionCount> sessionCounts; where key is String representation of Date and Number. You can do a putOrIncrement operation.Since you have done a bit of digging I am not sure whether this approach would suit you or not

Comment: Please show your SessionCount class (or at least the definition of the member variables).